# usb-c cable is not charging laptops, but transmits video

Tags: external-display, cable, lg-monitor, usb-3.1-type-c

I've bought LG 27UD88-W recently and was going to connect it with type C cable.
The seller didn't include original one and **the one I was using with dell for both charging and transmitting video - didn't work with LG.**

It only shared video with the LG, but wasn't charging the laptop

LG support said that I need a special cable
https://lgparts.com/products/ead63809902

But I don't understand what is so special about their cable? I have a usb c cable that work with DELL perfectly.
Maybe monitor does not deliver enough power

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that charging the notebook works with the cable you have on hand?

Comment: What is the make and model of the current USB-C to USB-C cable you have?